A question about Dorroh extensions, rngs and coproducts
A rng is a ring without unit $1$, the Dorroh extension of $R$, or unitarization, denoted by $\hat{R}$, is the ring having as domain the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}\times R$, multiplicative identity $(1,0)$ and binary operations defined as:
$$\begin{align*}
(n_1, r_1) + (n_2, r_2) &= (n_1 + n_2, r_1 + r_2),\\
(n_1, r_1) \cdot (n_2, r_2) &= (n_1n_2, n_1r_2 + n_2r_1 + r_1r_2).
\end{align*}$$
The natural rng embedding $j : R\rightarrow \hat{R}$ s.t. $j(r) = (0, r)$ satisfies the following universal property:

For any ring $Q$ and any rng homomorphism $f : R \rightarrow Q$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $g : \hat{R} \rightarrow Q$ s.t. $f = g\circ j$."

This construction is functorial and is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor. Indeed, it maps subrng's in subrings, i.e. if $R\leq Q$, also $\hat{R}\leq\hat{Q}$ with the natural identification. Moreover, the universal property above is enough to conclude that whenever we have the coproduct of rng's $A=B*C$, then also $\hat{A}=\hat{B}\:\hat{*}\:\hat{C}$, with $\hat{*}$ denoting the coproduct in the category of rings (which exists since it is cocomplete).
1- Do you agree with this statement?
Now, if we consider an integral domain $K$, a $K$-rng is just a $K$-bimodule which is also a rng. $K$-ring's are defined analogously and are just the usual $K$-algebras.
2-The restriction of such a functor to the subcategory of $K$-rng's provides a functor from the category of $K$-rng's to the one of $K$-algebras? Is this still the left adjoint of the forgetful functor?
It seems to me that this is the case. Further, I think that both the unitarization from $\mathsf{Rng}$ to $\mathsf{Ring}$, and the unitarization from $K$-Rng to $K$-Ring preserves the rank of free objects, mapping a free ($K$-)rng $R$ with basis $X$ into a free ($K$-)ring $\hat{R}$ with basis $\{(0,x):x\in X\}$. Indeed, this is clearly a set of generators and the universal property follows from the universal property above and the fact that the mapping of the $\mathbb{Z}$ part of $\hat{R}$ is fixed by the image of the unit $(1,0)$.
For the sake of clarity, I precise the reason for my question. I'm trying to understand if there is a construction (or a functor) that, starting from the variety of $K$-rng's, with $K$ integral domain (where a $K$-rng is just a $K$-bimodule that is also a rng), and going to the category of $K$-algebras (which are defined similarly), brings free objects in free objects and preserves coproducts. I'm new to this topic and I thought one could use Dorroh extensions for this purpose. Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Please don't use mathjax to format text. In particular, you should typeset italic text with markdown, *rng* rather than $rng$.

Of course, you may remove the condition that $K$ is an integral domain. Any ring $K$ will work.

Let $K$ be a ring. The unitalization of a $K$-rng $R$ is the $K$-ring whose underlying $K$-bimodule is $K \oplus R$, with the unit $(1,0)$, and multiplication $(u,r) (u',r') = (uu', u r' + u' + r u'  + r r')$. This provides a left adjoint $U^{\mathrm{ad}} : \mathbf{Rng}_k \to \mathbf{Ring}_k$ to the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Ring}_k \to \mathbf{Rng}_k$. Left adjoints preserve all colimits, so yes, in particular $U^{\mathrm{ad}}$ preserves coproducts.
If $V : \mathbf{Ring}_k \to \mathbf{Set}$ and $W : \mathbf{Rng}_k \to \mathbf{Set}$ denote the other forgetful functors with left adjoints $V^{\mathrm{ad}}$ and $W^{\mathrm{ad}}$, we have $W U = V$, and therefore $V^{\mathrm{ad}} = (W U)^{\mathrm{ad}} \cong U^{\mathrm{ad}} W^{\mathrm{ad}}$. In other words, indeed $U^{\mathrm{ad}}$ maps a free $k$-rng on a set $X$ to the free $k$-ring on the set $X$.
It is not a coincidence that the unitalizations of semigroups, rngs, and $K$-rngs, all look the same. Here is the category-theoretic generalization:
Proposition. Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a monoidal category with finite coproducts that distribute over $\otimes$. Consider the categories $\mathbf{Alg}(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ and $\mathbf{Alg}_{nu}(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ of algebra objects resp. non-unital algebra objects in $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$; also known as monoid objects resp. semigroup objects. The forgetful functor
$$U : \mathbf{Alg}(\mathcal{C},\otimes) \to \mathbf{Alg}_{nu}(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$$
has a left adjoint
$$U^{\mathrm{ad}} : \mathbf{Alg}_{nu}(\mathcal{C},\otimes) \to \mathbf{Alg}(\mathcal{C},\otimes),$$
the unitalization. It maps a non-unital algebra object $(A , ~ m : A \otimes A \to A)$ to the algebra object $(1 \oplus A , n)$, where the morphism $n$ is defined by
$$(1 \oplus A) \otimes (1 \oplus A) \xrightarrow{\sim} 1 \oplus A \oplus A \oplus (A \otimes A) \xrightarrow{n'} 1 \oplus A$$
with
$$n'|_1 = \iota_1, \quad n'_A = \iota_A, \quad n'|_{A \otimes A} = \iota_A \circ m.$$
Some example applications:

$(\mathbf{Set},\times)$ : unitalization of semigroups
$(\mathbf{Ab},\otimes)$ : unitalization of rngs
$(\mathbf{BiMod}_K,\otimes_K)$: unitalization of $K$-rngs
$(\mathbf{Ban}_1,\widehat{\otimes}_{\pi})$: unitalization of non-unital Banach algebras

So these constructions are just formal. Side remark: The construction of the unitalization of $C^*$-algebras is not formal.
